# Connecting two x variables with no continuous line with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

could someone please help me to solve my problem?
I have a dataframe with x1, x2 and y. The x's represent the indexes i want to connect. The y is the high of the plot (could also be some other value).
I have no idea how to connect the points with matplotlib.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x1":[1,5,8,10], "x2":[3,6,9,13], "y":[1,1,1,1]})
```

Should look something like this.
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zip is your friend:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x1":[1,5,8,10], "x2":[3,6,9,13], "y":[1,3,2,4]})

plt.plot(*zip((df.x1, df.y), (df.x2, df.y)), color="blue")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thats it, Thank you!